# Should it be possible to call an instance method of a class without creating a new object of that class?

Tags: class, python-3.x, methods, instance

I can do this and I don't have any issues:

```
class MyClass:
    def introduce(self):
        print("Hello, I am %s, and my name is " %(self))

MyClass.introduce(0)
MyClass().introduce()
```

I'm using Visual Studio and Python 3.4.1. I don't understand why this doesn't throw an error since I'm basically setting the value of `this`. Is this a feature and I just shouldn't be doing this? Should I be checking if self is actually an instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: It will raise an error when you run it: `TypeError: unbound method introduce() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got int instance instead)`. You don't need to check `self` manually. However, in general it's OK to call an instance method on the class and provide the instance explicitly - `Class.instance_method(instance)` is equivalent to `instance.instance_method()`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks and yeah I understand all that, but for some reason I didn't get an error the output was `Hello, I am 0...` and `Hello I am <__main__.MyClass object at....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 when you do `MyClass.introduce()` introduce is not linked to any object. It's considered as a (standalone) function like any other function you would declare by itself. The fact that it is declared within a class is not relevant here. `introduce` is therefore called like any function: a function with one parameter.

When you do `MyClass().introduce()` (notice the first set of parentheses) introduce is considered as a method belonging to an object which is an instance of class `MyClass` hence the regular OO behavior of adding automatically the self parameter.

Note that this is different for python 2. In python 2 there is a check to verify that when called, the effective argument passed for the self parameter is indeed an object of the correct type, i.e. an instance of MyClass. If you try `MyClass.introduce(0)` in Python 2 you'll get: `unbound method introduce() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got int instance instead)`. This check doesn't exist in Python 3 anymore because the notion of unbound method no longer exist.

Comment: If the notion of and unbound method doesn't exist anymore why does it work without error? Or what should be done to disallow it being called without an instance?